# Render datatables doesn't work after ajax.reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a code for expired date check when the data expired row change it background color,like this
[success if expired date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNkCi.png)
but when I insert new row or search data **background color is disappears**,when `table.ajax.reload();`

> my ajax render script

```
"aoColumns": [
                ../
                { "mData": "expired",
                "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    var today = '<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>';
                    if (data < today) {
                        $("td")
                        .filter(function() { return $.text([this]) == data; })
                        .parent()
                        .addClass("expired-date");
                        return '<td>'+data+'</td>';
                    }
                    else {
                        $("td")
                        .filter(function() { return $.text([this]) == data; })
                        .parent()
                        .removeClass("expired-date");
                        return '<td>'+data+'</td>';
                    }
                }
            },
```

how does the background color not disappear after `table.ajax.reload();`?

Comment: Am confused.   1. background color is disappears,when table.ajax.reload();  2. the background color not disappear after table.ajax.reload();

Comment: 1.background color work after refresh page 2.when I insert new row or search data,background color is disappears after `table.ajax.reload();`

Comment: I am remove `.filter()` and change `$("td")` to `$("td:contains('"+data+"')")` still disappears

Comment: Have you tried my solution? It should work perfectly.

Comment: You still compare date strings rather than date values which will cause errors and you re-apply class to every row N (row number) times causing unpredictable output.

Comment: Also, you don't need to have two identical rows `return '<td>'+data+'</td>';`, you can simply put those outside of `if... else...` if you need that at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to modify entire row style by assigning 'expired-date' class for outdated entries it is more logical to use [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option, e.g. like this:

```
$('#yourTableId').DataTable({
    ...
    createdRow: (tr, data) => new Date(data.expired.split('/').reverse().join('/')) < (new Date()).setHours(0,0,0,0) ? $(tr).addClass('expired-date') : true
});
```

Also, you don't need to inject today serverside, you may get it user end just like I did above, assuming you got your dates in `DD/MM/YYYY` format as it can be seen on your screenshot. Otherwise, if user didn't refresh the entire page for a few days he may get unexpected results as certain entries will not get highlighted.

Comment: I change my `"render"` to [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) it works, thank you